# Solve and integral equation with symmetric kernel

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, integral-equations, sturm-liouville

I have the following integral equation with symmetric kernel
$$
x(t)=\sin(\pi t)+\pi \cos (\pi t) +\lambda  \int_{0}^{1} k(t,s)x(s)\,ds $$
where $k(x,t)$ is a symmetric kernel given by
$$k(t,s)= 
\begin{cases}
(t+1)s, & 0 < t <s \\
(s+1)t,  & s < t <1 
\end{cases} $$
I want to find its eigenvalues and its eigenfunctions.

The first thing I do is to consider the homogeneous problem, i.e. the associated homogeneous integral equation
$$
x(t)=\lambda\int_{0}^{1}k(t,s)x(s)ds.
$$
By taking the derivative with respec to $t$ twice in this equation I obtain the following second order ordinary differential equation
$$
x''(t)=\lambda x(t)
$$
which with the boundary conditions $x(0)=x'(0)$ and $x(1)=x'(1)$ becomes the following [Robin boundary problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_boundary_condition)
$$
\begin{cases}
x''(t)=\lambda x(t)\\
x(0)=x'(0)\\
x(1)=x'(1)
\end{cases}
$$
I quickly solved this problem, but now I am not sure on how to procede in order to solve the former eigenvalue/eigenfunction problem. I know that is a Sturm-Liouville problem, but I'm somewhat confused on how to deal with this kind of boundary conditions.

I will be very grateful for any hint or help.

Comment: It's not clear what is your  question: do you want to solve the integral equation, or do you want to find the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of the integral operator? (By the way, how did you obtain those boundary conditions?)

Comment: I haven't checked your computations, but $\ddot{x} = \lambda x$ corresponds to the equation of motion of a harmonic oscillator of frequency $\omega = \sqrt{\lambda}$, which is solved by $x(t) = A\cos(\omega t) + B\sin(\omega t)$, where the constants of integration $A$ and $B$ are found with the help of the boundary conditions.